# Magento - Central Repository for MultiChannel(including POS), Multiple Store Multiple Location E-Commerce

Tags: magento, location, inventory, multistore

I am new to Magento and deciding on its feasibility. (Client wants to use Magento)
My main concern is to make a central inventory repository for Multichannel(amazon,ebay,POS), Multi Store/Merchants , Multi Location.

Does Magento itself offers these features or I will have to get some external application to be integrated with Magento?
I need ideas and suggestions.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [Wise Robot http://wiserobot.com/.](http://wiserobot.com/) They have a Magento extension that imports orders from various channels into Magento website.